# Finding object using prefix value and wildcard

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, lodash

I have a page that generates 3 objects with a prefix and a number.

The number changes everytime but the prefix will always remain.

It looks like this:

```
window.ctx8

window.ctx9

window.ctx10
```

On my page I have 3 lists, each list corresponds with 1 of these objects and I need to find the values of the selected items in that list using

```
window.["ctx" + ?NUMBER? ].selectedItems
```

How do I go through the window object and find these 3 objects efficiently?

EDIT: I have no control over how these objects are created, they're created by the application.

I have tried something like this:

```
Object.keys(window).filter(x => _.startsWith(x, "ctx"))
```

But I'm not sure how to further filter for a `random number`

Maybe I can do a length comparison as it will usually be a number between 0-99.

Comment: @AndrewLi - the point is the OP doesn't know what `NUMBER` is, just that properties/variables named `"ctx"` plus *some* number will exist.

Comment: I would put it in a different Object, because `window` has other properties, which could make a longer that desirable for in loop, but there should not be `.` after `window`. You can loop over any Object with a for in loop, just don't expect the results to be in the order you want.

Comment: @nnnnnn, i thank you, yes I don't know the property name but I know it starts with ctx + "random number"

Comment: @PHPglue unfortunately I can't control this aspect of the application

Comment: I would talk to the higher ups before implementing poor design.

Comment: @PHPglue I'm working with SharePoint Server from Microsoft. There's really nothing I can do about it unfortunately.

Comment: Using the `window` as a wrapper is overkill (`window` already have tons and tons of properties that may slow the search). Use another object (you can attach it to the `window` if you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get the names of the three properties as an array is as follows:

```
var ctxNames = Object.keys(window).filter(function(v) { return /^ctx\d+$/.test(v) })
// ctxNames is now ["ctx8", "ctx9", "ctx10"]
```

That is, use a regular expression to match "ctx" followed by one or more digits.

Looping through all of `window`'s properties doesn't take long, though if you were keen you could make the code more efficient by declaring the regex in a variable before the `.filter()` call rather than creating a new regex object in the callback.

Comment: This works really well. I was thinking of doing a length text but a regex is preferred.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean in your edit? `declaring the regex in a variable` Do you mean something like this `var textCtx = function(prop) { return /^ctx\d+/.test(prop) }` then `var ctxs = Object.keys(window).filter(textCtx})`

Comment: I don't think it is necessary, because the code as is runs fairly quickly even if `window` has 20,000 properties (and it seems more likely to have no more than a few hundred), but I just meant something like `var regex = /^ctx\d+$/`, and then in the function use `return regex.test(v)`.

Comment: @Batman Why are you using the `window` and not some other (empty) object as a wrapper? It would be much much faster if you wrap your vars in an empty object (then, if you want, add that object into the `window`).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir the objects are created by an application called SharePoint. It's a Microsoft Server application. I can't make any change there unfortunately. So i have to work like this.

Comment: @Batman Do you have an idea on the maximum number there could be after `"ctx"`? Or wether or not those numbers are successive?

Comment: 1000 milliseconds is 1 second. Poor design adds up.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir and @PHPglue - I think we can all agree that not relying on globals would be better, but if that is the requirement because of things outside the OP's control, the bottom line is that even several million properties can be filtered with a regex in a few hundred milliseconds, and an actual normal number of `window` properties (say, a few hundred like on this current SO page) can be filtered in less than one millisecond - not one millisecond each, but *in total*...

Comment: I appreciate all the concern and yes you're all right, it's not the best approach but Microsoft has placed these variables on the `window` and there's nothing I can really do about that unfortunately.